# Google Sheet OnChange trigger to copy incoming row but needs to Split into multiple rows (based on column)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with the 'Form Responses' sheet being populated by an external integration (JotForm).
I have an onChange trigger which responds to the incoming row, and copies the data to either one worksheet or another (Quote or Order based on a specific column value).  This works fine, but I would like to split the row into multiple rows - using a 'new line' delimiter that will be present in one of the fields.  The purpose of this is to enable granular updates to line items by a 3rd party.

[Image of incoming data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDjLC.png)

[Image or resulting data that I wish to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf7bm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be something like this:

```
function main() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data  = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var table = split_rows(data);

  sheet
    .clearContents()
    .getRange(1,1,table.length,table[0].length)
    .setValues(table);
}


function split_rows(data) {
  var rows = [];

  while (data.length) {
    var row = data.shift();
    var items = row[4].split('\n');

    while(items.length) {
      var item = items.shift();
      rows.push([row[0], ...row.slice(2,4), item, ...row.slice(5)]);
    }
  }
  
  return rows;
}
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

**Update**

Here is the example of the main function that takes a last row from the active sheet, splits it (with the same as above function `split_rows()`) and appends the result rows at the end of the sheet 'Sheet2':

```
function main_append_rows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var last_row = data.pop();
  var new_rows = split_rows([last_row]);

  var dest_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  while(new_rows.length) dest_sheet.appendRow(new_rows.shift());
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This code would work for the whole sheet though yeah - ie as a one off?  I would need this to work each incoming new row in Form Responses, and append as many rows as required in the second sheet.

Comment: This is exactly why I've made two functions. The function `split_rows()` takes a range, it can be any range (all the sheet, several rows, or just one row) and returns 2D array which you can paste on any sheet, etc. In my example the function `main()` sends all the sheet as `data`. You can send just one row if you want. But you haven't provided your code. It's impossible to guess the context where you will call the function and how you suggested to process its return. It's up to you to implement the algorithm. Or share your code.

Comment: I just added to my answer the example of the main function that takes a last row and appends it (after splitting) at the end of another sheet.

Comment: That's great stuff.  And looks like I can adapt to my needs. I wonder, could you provide any explanation of the line:

rows.push([row[0], ...row.slice(2,4), item, ...row.slice(5)]);

I can see it's something like building the array up with the first column, then the 3rd column (and 4 further fields), but I don't get how this doesn't conflict with the item itself which is the same column.

Comment: `[row[0], ...row.slice(2,4), item, ...row.slice(5)]` is the same as `[row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], item, row[5], ...and the rest cells]`. Yes it just builds a new row from the array. At the moment when it builds the row the variable `item` contains one of the lines of the multiline cell.